# How Can I Split A SQL Statement String Into Multiple Lines?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

```
DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @STRING ='SELECT FirstLine AS FL SELECT SecondLine AS SL'
  PRINT LEN(@STRING)
  PRINT @STRING+
        CASE 
          WHEN LEN(@STRING)>2 THEN (@STRING+@NewLineChar)
          ELSE @STRING 
         END
```

Comment: This appears to be working. What is the expected output?

Comment: output should be like this                                    SELECT FirstLine AS FL SELECT SecondLine AS SL SELECT FirstLine AS FL
SELECT SecondLine AS SL

Comment: Can you please show that expect output formatted in your question? It's hard to tell what you really want in the comment text.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this:

```
DECLARE @Delimiter VarChar(30) = 'SELECT';
DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13);
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @STRING ='SELECT FirstLine AS FL SELECT SecondLine AS SL';

PRINT REPLACE(@STRING, @Delimiter, @NewLineChar + @Delimiter);
```

The output is:

```
 SELECT FirstLine AS FL 
 SELECT SecondLine AS SL
```

I'm not sure why you were looking for a length greater than `2` given the output you requested.